# How would you tweak my recursive Coin Sum algorithm solution?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, debugging, recursion, combinations

I'm working on a Coin Sum problem:

*Given a set of available denominations and a target amount, I want to get the number of combinations that sum up to that target amount. Of each denomination I can take as many as I want.*

#### Example:

Input:

- denominations: [1, 5, 10]
- target amount: 10

Expected output: 4

Explanation: I can take the following counts of the corresponding denominations:

[10, 0, 0], [5, 1, 0], [0, 2, 0] or [0, 0, 1]

#### My Code

```
function func(denomenations, targetSum) {
  let totalCombos = 0;
  function generate(denomsLeft, remainder) {
    if(remainder === 0){
      totalCombos += 1;
      return
    }
    if(remainder - denomsLeft[0] >= 0) {
      generate(denomsLeft, remainder - denomsLeft[0])
    }
    if(remainder - denomsLeft[1] >= 0) {
      denomsLeft.splice(0,1)
      generate(denomsLeft, remainder - denomsLeft[0])
    }
  }
  generate(denomenations, targetSum)
  return totalCombos
}
```

#### The problem

I'm sure my solution quite close but something's just a bit off.

Calling `func([1,5,10],10)` returns 3 instead of 4. I don't seem to get the combination of coins that is 5 & 5 = 10.

Where is the error, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to [so]! It’s quite unclear what you’re asking—why should the function return 4 or anything? What is it supposed to do? Please [edit] to clarify. (PS if you’re trying to count combinations which sum to a target, I would just generate the valid combinations as a list, filter them on sum == target, and return the length of that list)

Comment: `.splice` mutates the array. I'd rather do `denomsLeft = denomsLeft.slice(1);` there.

Comment: @d.ben it's at least clear for me ... Also your proposed solution doesn't work for an infinite number of possible combinations. The solution the OP came up is far more efficient.

Comment: @JonasWilms the goals of the OP’s code are not actually stated, and OP admits it’s buggy—how should I go about determining what the bug is if I don’t know the goal? I won’t guess, though I did. Also: infinite combinations?? A finite set has only a finite number of possible combinations. Recursion wouldn’t work there either (if such a thing as infinite combinations existed for a finite set).

Comment: @JonasWilms i was almost certain that switching to slice from splice would fix it! but alas, the solution still only catches 3 out 4 combinations that sum to target 10 with denominations of [1,5,10]...

Comment: @D.BenKnoble this algorithm is a classic combinations problem where i need to find how many ways you can make change for a certain amount given a certain number of denominations.  in my example, i'm looking for combinations that add to 10 given denominations of [1,5,10] .  the answer here is 4 combinations however my implementation only returns 3 combinations

Comment: ....and what have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 3):

There are some mistakes in your code:

- `if(remainder - denomsLeft[1] >= 0) {` should have `[0]` instead of `[1]`
- You should not mutate `denomsLeft` with `splice`, as it will affect results in the rest of the recursive search (also after backtracking). Instead, create a copy without the first element, and pass that on.
- Also, when you decide to *not* use the first denomination anymore, you should not deduct it from `remainder`. So taking this together with the previous point, you should do:

  ```
  generate(denomsLeft.slice(1), remainder)
  ```
- You would then also need a check to see that there are still denominations left:

  ```
  if (!denomsLeft.length) return;
  ```

This will fix it. But I would also advise to:

- put the `>=` condition at the start of the function (as its opposite, to bail out).
- Use another name than the meaningless `func`
- End statements with a semi-colon consistently, as you don't want to leave that to the parser to decide.

So this will be the resulting code:

```js
function func(denomenations, targetSum) {
  let totalCombos = 0;
  function generate(denomsLeft, remainder) {
    if (remainder < 0) return;
    if (remainder === 0){
      totalCombos += 1;
      return
    }
    if (!denomsLeft.length) return;
    generate(denomsLeft, remainder - denomsLeft[0])
    generate(denomsLeft.slice(1), remainder)
  }
  generate(denomenations, targetSum)
  return totalCombos
}

console.log(func([1,5,10],10)); // 4
console.log(func([1,2,5],5)); // 4
```

Comment: with regards to generate(denomsLeft.slice(1), remainder - denomsLeft[0]), does passing denomsLeft.slice(1) as an argument reassign the value of the denomsLeft variable prior to the function being evaluated?  If so, this means that the second argument -- remainder - denomsLeft[0] -- is evaluated using the already "sliced" array.  Is that correct?

Comment: additionally, calling coinSumCombis( [1, 2, 5], 5) returns 6, but should return 4

Comment: Concerning your last comment: indeed, I updated my answer to fix that. Concerning your first remark: every function execution has its own `denomsLeft` variable. By calling it with `denomsLeft.slice(1)` you don't change the current execution's variable, but you do determine the one in the recursive function's execution context.

Comment: Did this answer the question?

Comment: nicely done, and yes - that does make sense.  The only thing i'm stuck on is why i can't subtract denomsLeft[1] from remainder -- ie generate(denomsLeft.slice(1), remainder - denomsLeft[0]) -- but i've found a pretty useful and relevant video so i will keep looking into it

Comment: The reason for *not* subtracting is that it is the alternative for the previous recursive call, where you do subtract it. The idea is, that once you decide to not take any more of the same denomination, you remove it from the available ones (hence: slice). It makes no sense to first not choose it, and then, further down the recursion, to come back to that decision and choose that denomination again. As we remove it from the choices, we should also not subtract its value (we did not *take* that denomination).

Comment: ok. that makes total sense.  now, if we were to generate(denomsLeft.slice(1), remainder - denomsLeft[1]) , why does this change our outcome?  by subtracting denomsLeft[1] from remainder, we're essentially generating what would be the subsequent recursive call, but the outputs render 3 instead of 4.  I can't seem to wrap the ol' head around that.

Comment: If you do that, you will never consider the possibility where absolutely none of a certain denomination is selected (while still needing coins to reach the target). Whichever of the two recursive calls you go into, you'll at least have taken one of the current denomination. So, by *not* subtracting, you give the possibility to completely skip a denomination. This is important to find 5 & 5 in the main example (by not taking any from 1).

Answer (score 2):

Trincot gave [an excellent analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60477233) of what was wrong with your code and how to fix it.

I would like to point out, though, that there are simpler techniques than the method in the question and in trincot's clean-up.

Here is how I might do it:

```js
const coinCount = (denoms, target) => 
  target == 0 
    ? 1
  : denoms.length == 0 || target < 0
    ? 0
  : // else 
    coinCount (denoms, target - denoms[0]) + coinCount (denoms.slice (1), target)


console .log (coinCount ([1, 5, 10], 10))
console .log (coinCount ([1, 5, 10, 25], 100))
```

We test whether the target is `0`.  If it is we return `1`.  If this seems surprising, let's remember that there *is* one way to total zero: we return no coins at all!

If the target isn't zero and we have no denominations left, or if our target is negative, there are no coin combinations available and we return `0`.

Finally, we can make a choice.  We either use a coin of the first denomination or we don't.  If we do, then we recur with the same set of denominations, and the total less the value of that denomination.  If we don't, then we cannot use it later, so we recur with the remaining denominations and the current total.  Adding the counts returned by those two choices gives us our total.

We can see that the recursion is sound since each recursive step either reduces the total we're searching for (and hence we'll eventually hit a number no larger than zero) or it reduces the number of denominations (and hence we'll eventually hit zero.)  Either way, we will eventually hit one of our base cases.

Using destructuring, we might choose a variation on this instead:

```js
const coinCount = ([denom = undefined, ...denoms], target) => 
  target == 0 
    ? 1
  : denom == undefined || target < 0
    ? 0
  : coinCount ([denom, ...denoms], target - denom) + coinCount (denoms, target)
```

In some ways I like this variant better, but either one seems to more cleanly express the fundamental recursion in the problem.

I think either variant of this technique is overall simpler, especially as the original  depends on side-effects in the inner `generate` function.  This version is a pure function and uses only a single expression.